# Why does debugger say that the documented OpenLaszlo lz.FocusService.getFocus() method doesn't exist

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

The lz.Focus reference manual documentation for the latest official release (4.9.0) of the OpenLaszlo programming platform (http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps4.9/docs/reference/) gives many examples of calling methods on the lz.FocusService object, however, many of the examples do not work:

eg:

```
lz.FocusService.getFocus();
```

Calling this command responds in the following debugger window error:

> TypeError: Error #1006: getFocus is not a function.

Why do I get this error trying to use it?

Comment: I have to say that I find the documentation a bit confusing as well.

Comment: That's the documentation style for class methods. The docs do state that "lz.Focus is the single instance of the class lz.FocusService." `lz.FocusService.getFocus()` is only for the method documentation of the `getFocus()` method of that class.  
Check the doc page for the [lz.BrowserService class](http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps4.9/docs/reference/lz.BrowserService.html). Class methods are documented using  
 `lz.BrowserService.loadURL(url : String, target : String, features : String);`  
but the LZX example uses the single instance:  
`lz.Browser.loadURL('{some_url}';, '_blank');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenLaszlo 4.9.0 reference manual documentation is confusing. Calling the lz.Focus object (instead of lz.FocusService) with the same method names seems to work.

eg:

```
lz.Focus.getFocus();
```

This does not give an error.

Comment: Note: Opened up an official OpenLaszlo JIRA ticket to have this corrected here: http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-10282

Comment: It's not a bug, but a feature which is not documented well.

Comment: @bork999 I updated the answer to replace the word 'incorrect' with 'confusing'. I'll leave the Jira open to see if anyone from OpenLaszlo agrees the documentation should be improved or not.

Comment: Good, that makes sense. Given the very reduced level of activity I'm not optimistic to see any work on the documentation done very soon.